# How to use delete command with less than operator in condition with avg() method;

Tags: sql

I want to delete the details of a vendor whose stock is less than the average amount.

The given query does not work:

```
delete from Vendor where Stock_details<(select avg(Stock_details) from vendor);
```

Comment: What db engine are you using?

Comment: in **mysql** the above query works.

Comment: That seems like an odd query - do you realize if you run it multiple times, you will eventually be down to just the vendor(s) with the highest `Stock_details`?

Answer (score 1):

If your query doesn't work, it is probably because you are using MySQL.  This is standard SQL.

You can fix this with the double subquery approach:

```
delete from Vendor
    where Stock_details < (select a from (select avg(Stock_details) as a from vendor));
```